How to list down all of dbt models and their last person that modified them?
A little bit of context, I'm not aware of all of the dbt models that my new team made in the past, but for sure I know all of their names.
So, if possible, I'd like to list down all of the models in my dbt project with their respective last modifier, more or less like this:



model
last_modifier
last_modified




summary_transaction.sql
Alex Monfils
2024-05-01



Is that possible? Thanks!

That's probably best done using your version control provider API (e.g. GitHub API): fetch all SQL files from your repo, and then check which user made the last commit to each of these files.
